# The multi-part identifier could not be bound. T-SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I am trying to run this select statement:

```
SELECT  dbo.tblBird.EnglishName, dbo.tblMember.Last
FROM  dbo.tblBird , dbo.tblMember
JOIN dbo.tblBirdMember AS join1 ON  (join1.BirdID = dbo.tblBird.BirdID)
JOIN dbo.tblBirdMember AS join2 ON (join2.MemberID = dbo.tblMember.MemberID)
```

but I get this error:

```
Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
The multi-part identifier "dbo.tblBird.BirdID" could not be bound.
```

I have been searching around on google for hours but I can't seem to get this going, and help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You are missing a join `ON` condition. Also: don't mix implicit joins (`,` syntax) with explicit joins (`JOIN ... ON` syntax).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to write something like:

```
select b.EnglishName, c.Last
from dbo.tblBirdMember a
join dbo.tblBird b          on a.BirdID = b.BirdID
join dbo.tblMember c        on a.MemberID = c.MemberID
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I was trying to do! I see where I was going wrong now. Thank you!

Comment: Yes - if you alias your table as _join1_, then you have to refer to the table as _join1_ in your `ON` condition.